# Where are desktop enviroment texture packs found?

Tags: desktop-environments

On mac OS there is a directory where you can put images in to replace default screens like the booting screen. Is there an equivalent for desktop enviroments like gnome, unity, kde, lxde, sfce etc.?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Sorry set it as answered.

Comment: Please test it at your convenience and accept only if it answers your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu themes are available in the `/usr/share/themes/` directory.

All default backgrounds are in `/usr/share/backgrounds/`.

However the boot splash screen is not part of the usual themes and managed by low-level components ([plymouth](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/plymouth)) and unless you know what you're doing it's often discouraged to change the splash screen picture.